# Swift: Calling .requestLocation() while app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, core-location, cllocationmanager

If I call `.requestLocation()` in the background of my app, the `locationManager didUpateLocations` method is never called. It works when the app is open. I've set `.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true` and the test phone selected `.authorizedAlways` for authorization status. Does `requestLocation` not work in the background?

To clarify, I'm calling it within the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` delegate method. Every time I send a remote push notification to the device, I want `.requestLocation()` to be called if app in background. Is that impossible?

`didReceiveRemoteNotification`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`?

Comment: added it to the original post.

Comment: You have verified that you are making it to `locationManager.requestLocation()`?  Also do you have `didUpateLocations` in your `appDelegate` to handle the update?

Comment: Yes, I added a breakpoint at locationManager.requestLocation() and when I send a push and the app is backgrounded it hits the breakpoint. I do have didUpdateLocations in the appDelegate. They work in the foreground, but not the background as of late.

Comment: `requestLocation` completes asynchronously, but you are calling the completion handler before you have a location update, which will terminate your background execution. You should try restructuring your code so that you call `beginBackgroundTask`/`endBackgroundTask` and don't call the completion handler until you have the location update.

Comment: @Paulw11 I though those were called in applicationDidEnterBackground. Is there an example of how I could call them inside another method?

Comment: You can use those any time you need extended execution in the background. You call them the same way. I would create an optional `DispatchGroup` property, have you remote notification set it, call `enter` and then set up a `notify` to set the dispatch group to `nil` and if the dispatch group isn't nil in `didUpdateLocations` call `leave` on it

Comment: Using a DispatchGroup worked! Thank you @Paulw11.

Comment: Did you need `beginBackgroundTask` as well?  Probably not if the location callback occurs quickly.

Comment: I didn't, just dispatchGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `requestLocation` will complete asynchronously; it may take some time to determine the user's location and call the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method.

Calling the `completionHandler` tells iOS that you have finished background processing.  As you do this immediately after `requestLocation` iOS suspends your app before the location delegate is called.

You can use a `DispatchGroup` to determine when the location has been retrieved and you are ready to be suspended:

```
class AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var backgroundDispatchGroup: DispatchGroup?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {

            self.backgroundDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
            self.backgroundDispatchGroup?.enter()
            locationManager.requestLocation()

            self.backgroundDispatchGroup?.notify {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
                self.backgroundDispatchGroup = nil
            }

         } else {
             completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
         }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // Do whatever with the location

        self.backgroundDispatchGroup?.leave()
    }
}
```